# Postgres Master and Slave(s) balancer

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have set up my own master and slave Postgres in my kubernetes cluster.

Now I would like to check if it is possible to have a load balancer that checks if the transaction is **Read** or **INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE**.

If it is **READ** then the load balancer automaticaly routes the request to the slave(s). Otherwise if it is **INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE** then route it to the master.

As much as possible I'm looking for a Postgres solution for this.

Note: I'm running my kubernetes in my raspberry pi.

Comment: A single transaction may consist of multiple queries, you cannot predict beforehand what next query will be before you have sent it.

Comment: Postgres has removed all instances of "slave" from its source code and manual. https://www.postgresql.org/search/?u=%2Fdocs%2F12%2F&q=slave Do you mean "follower" or "standby"? Or is this kubernetes nomenclature?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter they have not removed `master` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html so the question meaning is pretty obvious isn't it

Comment: @zerkms so the term should have been ```master``` and ```standby```. So there is no such solution?

Comment: @JaysonGonzaga usually solution is that you have 2 different services (one that directs traffic to master, and the other that connects to standby), and then from the client you pick the right one (manually).

Comment: yeah that's what I am thinking of